# why laravel View::make do not work?

Tags: laravel

Today i met a problem when i learned laravel:
The Laravel route works

> Route::make('test',function()
>   {
>   echo 'success';
>   })

I could get success when I enter public/test

but when I used return View::make('hello');

> Route::make('test',function()
>   {
>   return View::make('hello');
>   })

It would not go to hello.blade.php if I enter public/test

It really confuse me,who can give me a answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Route::make()`. Did you mean `Route::get()`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
Route::get('test',function() { return View::make('hello'); });
```

The method you have to call is the http method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) which will be used to access your route:

```
Route::get(...);
Route::post(...);
Route::delete(...);
Route::put(...);
```

But you also can use `any`, which will accept everything:

```
Route::any(...);
```